# Passing Data from TableViewController to another TableViewController embedded in container

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm having trouble passing data from a `TableViewController` to another `TableViewController` that is embedded in a `Container View`. When I pass the data in `prepareForSegue` I get hit with a "Could not cast value of type `UIViewController` to `TableViewControllerEmbeddedInContainer`. Do I have to create a file for the container `ViewController` and catch anything in there? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

**In my first TableViewController:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

self.myFavText = "My Favorite Text"
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("favDetails", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let myDetails = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewControllerEmbeddedInContainer
details.myFav = self.myFavText

}
```

Comment: Your destination vc is the container vc not the embedded vc. You need to extract embedded vc from the container vc somehow and set the text directly, or you can use containers view did load to do the magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kampbell411,

*"Do I have to create a file for the container ViewController and catch anything in there?"*

Answer : YES.

*"When I pass the data in prepareForSegue I get hit with a "Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController to TableViewControllerEmbeddedInContainer'"*

Answer : You cant because segue is pointing to the ViewController containing UIContainerView and not the ViewController embeded in it :)

**How to Solve :)**

Create a class for ViewController containing ContainerView. Create an IBOutlet for ContainerView :)

Lets call it as Intermediate class and view as myContainer :)

```
class Intermediate: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myContainer: UIView!
    var value : String!


    //catch the embeded segue get the ViewController reference lets call it as Testing 

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let test = segue.destinationViewController as! Testing
        test.value = self.value
    }
}
```

This should help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
       self.myFavText = "My Favorite Text"
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("favDetails", sender: self)

}
```

you will pass the value in Container ViewController class, then assign the value to TableViewControllerEmbeddedInContainer class.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if (segue.identifier == "favDetails") {

       var myDetails = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
       myDetails.myFav = self.myFavText 

    }
}
```

hope its helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the ContainerViewController, would I just have  `var myFav: String!` to catch that value? I tried that and then assigned the value and got nil. @Iyyappan

Comment: set the breakpoint in `prepareForSegue` method, its check if condition is true or false?